# Display XY Format to Shapefile (Scale)

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, latitude-longitude, precision

Using ArcView 10.1 and using excel for Lat/Long conversion to a shapefile.  The original Lat/Long has 7 numerical characters past the decimal point xx.1143717.  When I convert this excel into a shapefile, the numbers are shortened down to 6.  The Lat of ex.. xx.1143717 when converted into a shapefile is brought down to 6 numbers past the decimal and rounded up to xx.1143720

Is there a way, or how can I make it where all the Lat/Long numbers are shown, all 7 instead of 6 in the attribute table?

Comment: Do you need the full seven digits for attribute purposes or for location-precision purposes?  That is: are the features being mis-plotted when you bring them in from excel and you need that extra digit for spatial precision purposes.  Or, do you need the unchanged number because you need it in its original form for analysis purposes?

Comment: I need it for precision purposes.  I looked at the state website for the oil/gas well location and they are very close to each other.  On my map, the 2 wells are sharing the same symbol instead of seperate well symbols.

Comment: my back of the envelope calculation shows the error by this rounding is <1 foot

Comment: Are you using a .csv file as an intermediate step?

Comment: Just excel spreadsheet 97-03

Comment: There really is not much distance difference with the round up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the numeric properties of the fields containing the latitude and longitude information.  Open the attribute table and right click on the field heading you would like to adjust, then click properties.  Next click on the box with three dots [...] next to the word numeric and a new window will pop up.  In this new window change the number of decimal places to the amount required, in this case 7.